# What is the point of PHP's stripslashes function?

Tags: php, mysqli

Suppose you have the following:

```
<?php

    $connection = mysqli_connect("host", "root", "passwd", "dbname");

    $habits = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['habits']);

?>
```

Lets say you entered, for a field called 'habits', the value 'tug o' war'. Therefore, the mysqli_real_escape_string function will escape the second quote symbol and the database engine won't be fooled into thinking that the value is 'tug o'. Instead, it will know that the value is actually 'tug o' war'. My question is, why then do you need a stripslashes function? A stripslashes function will simply strip away the good work that was done by the mysqli_real_escape_string function. Stripping away a backslash will simply return you to where you were, and the database will be fooled again. Am I to assume that the stripslashes function is NOT used for database purposes? That is, would this piece of code be completely nonsensical?:

```
<?php

    $connection = mysqli_connect("host", "root", "passwd", "dbname");

    $habits = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['habits']);

    $undosomething = stripslashes($habits);

    echo '$undosomething';

?>
```

If stripslashes is NOT used for database purposes, what exactly is it used for?

Comment: It shouldn't need to be used these days, just part of the historic legacy of PHP; even as you shouldn't be using mysqli_real_escape_string either, but using bind variables instead

Comment: Mostly it's for stripping slashes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per the [Manual](http://www.php.net/stripslashes), the purpose of stripslashes() is to unquote a quoted string, meaning to remove a backslash quoting a character. Note, PHP lacks a character data type, so all single characters are strings.  You may wish to peruse this [example code](https://3v4l.org/sO0XO#output) which demonstrates that this function leaves forward slashes as well as [escape sequences](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.escape.php) involving non-printable characters unaltered. Stripslashes() arose to counter excessive quoting caused by a feature that PHP formerly supported: magic quotes.

In the early days of PHP when Rasmus Lerdorf worked with databases that necessitated escaping the single quote character, he found a way to avoid the tedium of manually adding a backslash to quote or escape that character; he created *magic quotes*:

```
    ... useful when mSQL or Postgres95 support is enabled
    since ... single quote has to be escaped when it is 
    part of [a] ... query ... 

                        (See php.h in PHP/FI [php-2.0.1] )
```

While magic quotes saved developers from having to use addslashes(), this feature could automatically quote inappropriately.  A form's input with a value of `O'Reilly` would display as `O\'Reilly`. Applying stripslashes() fixed that issue.  Though stripslashes() lived up to its name and stripped away backslashes, it was inadequate for addressing all the problems associated with magic quotes, a feature that would ultimately be deprecated in PHP5.3 and then removed as of PHP5.4 (see [Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php)).

You may view quoted data if you are still using a version of PHP that supports magic quotes.  For example, consider the case of a $_GET variable that originates from a JavaScript containing a url-encoded string, as follows:

```
location.href="next_page.php?name=O%27Riley"; // $_GET['name'] == O\'Riley
```

If you were to apply to $_GET['name'] either addslashes() or  mysqli_real_escape_string(), this variable's value would expand, containing two more backslashes, as follows:

```
O\\\'Riley
```

Suppose the variable were next used in an insert query.  Normally the backslash of a quoted character does not get stored in the database. But, in this case, the query would cause data to be stored as:

`O\'Riley`

The need for stripslashes() is much less likely nowadays, but it's good to still retain it. Consider the following JavaScript, containing a flagrant typo:

```
location.href="http://localhost/exp/mydog.php
?content=My%20dog%20doesn\\\\\\\\\\\\\%27t%20
like%20to%20stay%20indoors."
```

Using stripslashes(), one may dynamically correct the code as follows:

```
function removeslashes($string)
{
    while( strpos( $string, "\\" ) !== FALSE ) {
      $string = stripslashes( $string );
    }
    return $string;
}

$text = htmlentities($_GET['content']);
if (strpos($text,"\\") !== FALSE ) {
    echo removeslashes( $text );
}
```

Note: stripslashes() is not recursive.

Answer (score 3):

(As of 2014) It still has it's uses. It's not really used with a database but even with this, there are use cases. Let's assume, or send data from form using JavaScript and you have a string with a quote such as "It's". Than getting the value through the `$_GET` supervariable, you'll get the value "It's". If you than use `mysqli_real_escape_string()` or similar (which you must use for security), the quote will be double encoded and the backslash will be saved to the DB. For such scenarios, you would use this function. But it is not for security and not necessarily used with a DB.

Comment: My point is that if you find yourself using addslashes/stripslashes, you are probably doing something that has a much better solution... fixing the upstream data.  Obviously there are times when you might want to use these functions... and in those times you should think very carefully about whether or not it's a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

There is no point to `stripslashes()`.

Some folks used to think this provided them security, but as you can see it does not.  It should be removed from PHP completely, but it hasn't been.

Comment: While you should always use the most appropriate transformation based on the source/destination of data, there will be cases where this is not provided by any extension. In such cases stripslahes (and addslashes) is a great time saver. Deprecating and removing magic_quotes was a good thing for PHP - it was a badly designed interface to functionality which was mis-imolemented by a lot of extensions and needed to die. The same is NOT true of add/strip slashes.

Comment: @symcbean Can you provide a good example of when one should use `addslashes()`/`stripslashes()`?

Comment: I was trying to think any possible use case but failed.

Answer (score 1):

Neither `mysqli_real_escape_string` nor `stripslashes` protect against SQL injection.
Use prepared statements.
Example Code.

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "my_database");

/* Prepared statement, stage 1: prepare */
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO test(id) VALUES (?)");
$id = 1;
$stmt->bind_param("i", $id);
$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: Perhaps you know better than those on php.net :)
"Escapes special characters in a string for use in an SQL statement" http://us2.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php

Comment: Yes **mysqli_real_escape_string** escapes special characters. True:  **Prepared Statements** fast query and safe. Sory my English not good.

Comment: @SergiyT. Prepared queries are a better solution, but properly using escaping can work as well.  Prepared queries are better because you fundamentally separate the data from the command, meaning that injection cannot occur.  Escaping works but when only done absolutely correctly every single time.

Answer (score 1):

**addslashes()**:

[w3schools.com - function returns a string with backslashes in front of predefined characters.](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_addslashes.asp) 
[php.net - Quote string with slashes](http://php.net/manual/en/function.addslashes.php)

**stripslashes()**:

[w3schools.com - function removes backslashes added by the addslashes() function.](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_addslashes.asp) 
[php.net - Un-quotes a quoted string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php)

```
<?php
 
  $str = "Who's Peter Griffin?";
 
  echo $str . " This is original string." . PHP_EOL;
 
  echo addslashes($str) . " This is addslashes string." . PHP_EOL;
 
  echo stripslashes(addslashes($str)) . " This is stripslashes string."  . PHP_EOL;
 
?>
```

Embed PHP online:

```css
body, html, iframe { 
  width: 100% ;
  height: 100% ;
  overflow: hidden ;
}
```

```html
<iframe src="https://ideone.com/2DNzNJ"></iframe>
```

Comment: Nice job embedding your PHP answer!  Note, that stripslashes() will remove slashes whether or not they were added by addslashes(); see here: https://3v4l.org/R3A5v#output